# Fatal: pathspec 'file.txt' did not match any files, GIT

Tags: git

I have just started learing GIT. Follow their tutorial.

Now at the very beginning I got stuck with this error:

```
Fatal: pathspec 'file.txt' did not match any files.
```

Here is the screenshot of my procedure and commands:

[image]

What I am doing wrong here?

Comment: Not necessarily your case, you can see this with git 1.8.5 on the first `git add`, in an empty repo. It is being fixed: see [my answer below](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21078070/6309)

Answer (score 14):

The files don't exist, so they cannot be added. Make sure the files have been created first.

```
D:\temp\hi>git init
Initialized empty Git repository in D:/temp/hi/.git/

D:\temp\hi>dir
 Volume in drive D is Data
 Volume Serial Number is 744F-7845

 Directory of D:\temp\hi

2013-11-25  12:59 AM    <DIR>          .
2013-11-25  12:59 AM    <DIR>          ..
               0 File(s)              0 bytes
               2 Dir(s)  1,331,387,256,832 bytes free

D:\temp\hi>git add hi.txt
fatal: pathspec 'hi.txt' did not match any files

D:\temp\hi>echo hello > hi.txt

D:\temp\hi>git add hi.txt

D:\temp\hi>dir
 Volume in drive D is Data
 Volume Serial Number is 744F-7845

 Directory of D:\temp\hi

2013-11-25  12:59 AM    <DIR>          .
2013-11-25  12:59 AM    <DIR>          ..
2013-11-25  12:59 AM                 8 hi.txt
               1 File(s)              8 bytes
               2 Dir(s)  1,331,387,256,832 bytes free
```

Answer (score 10):

I was doing:

```
git add AppName/View Controllers/Sections/Devices/DeviceContainerViewController.swift
```

But was getting the following error:

> fatal: pathspec 'AppName/View' did not match any files

As you can see the command is breaking between View & Controllers because there's a space.

I just had to wrap my path into double quotes. It's not normally necessary, but when you have spaces you need to.

```
git add "AppName/View Controllers/Sections/Devices/DeviceContainerViewController.swift"
```

Comment: Well, I used your path that you follow because i have also spaces in my file name but i got different error "bash: !\Theory\Session: event not found" because i using git bash before error is "fatal: pathspec 'TheorySession' did not match any files". so i moved to cmd and tried your path it works. i think there is problem with git bash!!!

Answer (score 9):

In order to add a file to git it has to exist. `git add` does not create a file, but tells git to add it to the current branch you are on and track it.

Currently, you have no tracked files, as you can see from your `git status` command. In order to track all files from the *my-project* directory, do a `git add my-project/*`. This will add all the files from that directory.

Next, if you do not have the desired *file.txt*, just create a text file and run `git status`. It should show you that you have an untracked *file.txt* file, which you can afterwards add to git using `git add file.txt`.

Answer (score 4):

Note: you shouldn't see this particular error message in git 1.9/2.0 (Q1 2014).

See [commit 64ed07c](https://github.com/git/git/commit/64ed07cee0394509c65331f1e7acb36c58fd18fb) by [Nguyễn Thái Ngọc Duy (`pclouds`)](https://github.com/pclouds):

### `add`: don't complain when adding empty project root

This behavior was added in [07d7bed](https://github.com/git/git/commit/07d7bedda8d18ffbfe5960ce27b73a24c01cac1a) (`add`: don't complain when adding
empty project root - 2009-04-28, git 1.6.3.2)
then broken by [84b8b5d](https://github.com/git/git/commit/84b8b5d1fa244bc591291a3cf18bf0fa9976ad17) (remove `match_pathspec()` in favor of `match_pathspec_depth()` - 2013-07-14, git 1.8.5).

Reinstate it.

---

The idea is:

> We try to warn the user if one of their pathspecs caused no matches, as it may have been a typo. However, we disable the warning if the pathspec points to an existing file, since
>   that means it is not a typo but simply an empty directory.
>
> Unfortunately, the `file_exists()` test was broken for one special case: the pathspec of the project root is just "".
>   This patch detects this special case and acts as if the file exists (which it must, since it is the project root).
>
> The user-visible effect is that this:

```
$ mkdir repo && cd repo && git init && git add .
```

> used to complain like:

```
fatal: pathspec '' did not match any files
```

> but now is a silent no-op.

It is again a silent no-op in upcoming git 1.9/2.0 (Q1 2014)

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem because the file name is already appended with .txt and you are adding an extra .txt explicitly. You can try with this:

```
git add file.txt.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

In order to add a file to git it has to exist. `git add` does not create a file, but tells git to add it to the current branch you are on and track it. So you should create a new file in the command line :

```
MD <new file>
```

After that you add :

```
git add <new file>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just give a file path while adding file to git add command, it works for me

$ git add mainFolder/.../file.extension

Note: mainFolder would be the folder inside your repo

Answer (score 0):

I was also stuck over this. The solution is :
a) Make any txt file first let's say " Readme.txt "

b) Copy this text file to you local git repo(folder) eg- C:/store

c) Go to windows command prompt if you are on windows (type " cmd " on search bar when you click on window button )

d) go to your local git repo. type ** echo hello > Readme.txt**
---> C:\admin\store>echo hello > Readme.txt

**echo hello is a dos command which shows output status text to the screen or a file.**

Answer (score 0):

The file is not matched because `git add` creates your file in the root directory but it actually does not create a file, but tells git to add it to the current branch you are on (adds files from the working directory to the staging area) and track it with `git status` command. So,

**first create the .txt file and mention the path correctly!**
let there is

```
$ git add path/filename.txt
```

(Not for it only, for any git command for a change in staging area write the whole path of the filename with forwarding slash after the command )

e.g-

if your file is on the desktop then

```
$ git add C:Users/username/Desktop/filename.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you go! Very simple. Need to place the .txt file manually in the pwd mentioned folder...

suumapat@SUUMAPAT-IN MINGW64 ~/newproject (master)
$  git add abc.txt
fatal: pathspec 'abc.txt' did not match any files

suumapat@SUUMAPAT-IN MINGW64 ~/newproject (master)
$ dir

suumapat@SUUMAPAT-IN MINGW64 ~/newproject (master)
$ pwd
/c/Users/suumapat/newproject

suumapat@SUUMAPAT-IN MINGW64 ~/newproject (master)
$ dir
abc.txt

suumapat@SUUMAPAT-IN MINGW64 ~/newproject (master)
$ git add abc.txt

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue but with the Windows file system. Here was my solution that worked.

from the git project directory. Here is exactly what was displayed with the current directory.

D:\Projects\ReactNative\project>git add "scr/\components/\validate.js"

The file being entered into git was validate.js. It was in a directory under the project. That directory was src\components.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue as well. Please confirm your file directory.
After moving my file to the correct directory it works.

[image: git output]

Answer (score 0):

This error is raised because the file you are adding to the repository is not created. First create the file and then add it to the staging area:

```
touch filename
git add filename
```

Answer (score 0):

Before initiating the command "git add file.txt",

enter:

> echo file > file.txt

Then initiate the command:

> git add file.txt

This worked for me.

Comment: This article helped me out with the same issue I was having: https://cloudaffaire.com/faq/fatal-pathspec-file-txt-did-not-match-any-files-git/

Comment: CAUTION: That will erase any information that is already in that file. You should use double arrows 'echo file >> file.txt'

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue . make sure u create a file with desired extension by Using Touch command and then Add the file by git add filename.txt.

#create  a file
step1:touch filename.txt
Add the file
step2:git add filename.txt
#check for the file
step3:git status

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -4):

Use double quotes in the file name as shown below and it should work perfectly.

Error:

```
fatal: pathspec 'index.html' did not match any files
```

Solution:

```
git add "file_name"
```

Comment: double quotes are not required to add a file into the stagging area

Comment: The double quotes require only when there is a blank space in the file name...