# git add did not match any files

Tags: git, git-add

So I've set up my repository in /Desktop/GitHW6 and I've copied files over from a separate folder /xampp/htdocs/ikp1 into my GitHW6 folder. It's not letting me add any files into this, and keeps giving me the error message:

$ git add index.html

fatal: pathspec 'index.html' did not match any files

I've tried adding from the ikp1 folder and adding the files from GitHW6 folder. It either says it is outside of the repository or it did not match any files. I don't know what I'm doing wrong and other online resources are making this far more confusing than I think this needs to be. Thanks in advance.

Comment: When you're in your repo work folder and `git add index.html` fails, does `ls` show that there is in fact an `index.html` in the current folder?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Fatal: pathspec 'file.txt' did not match any files, GIT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20188229/fatal-pathspec-file-txt-did-not-match-any-files-git)

Comment: Check if the file index.html is present in the folder you execute the command $ git add index.html