# the "git add <file_name>" command leads to the error "fatal: pathspec 'file_name' did not match any files

Tags: git, github, git-bash, git-add

Before you mark as duplicate, I am referencing this similar question: [Fatal: pathspec 'file.txt' did not match any files, GIT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20188229/fatal-pathspec-file-txt-did-not-match-any-files-git/21078070)

However my issue seems slightly different from the one posted there.

I am a complete beginner with Git and GitHub.  I have already written a complete program and have followed the instructions to upload/commit it to my GitHub page.  It appears to have worked without any issues.

Later, as further practice, I edited the file containing the source code for my program.   All I am attempting to do is to upload/commit this newly edited version of my program to my GitHub page.  However when I attempt to enter the command:

```
git add <file_name>
```

I get the following message:

```
fatal: pathspec 'file_name' did not match any files
```

I thought it might be a syntax issue so I tried the "git add <file_name>" command both with and without the file extension ".txt"  I also tried the add command using the "/" instead of the file extension since that's how it appears in Git Bash when using the "git status" command.  Nothing has worked.
[image: git add error 1]

Then I noticed that when I use the "dir" command the file names are represented using a different syntax.  It appears that file names consisting of multiple words separated by spaces are represented with backslashes followed by a space and with no file extension, so my file: "Word Guess.txt" became "Word\ Guess" taking this into account I tried the "git add" command using this different file name representation and I wrote:

```
git add Word\ Guess
```

That gave me the following warning:

[image: git add error 2]

I don't fully understand the warning is saying but its obviously not the result I intended.  Clearly I am missing something here.  In the response given to the similar question that I referenced at the top of this post, the commenter said that the source of the problem was that the file did not exist and that you cannot add a file before creating it but in my case it seems obvious that the file exists because the program is fully functional and has already been successfully uploaded to my GitHub page.  What am I not grasping?

*Edit I am becoming even more confused now.  In the last screen shot the warning message said that:

```
if you added this path by mistake, you can remove it from the index with:
    git rm --cached Word Guess/bin
```

However after typing the command exactly as it appears in the Git Bash warning:

```
git rm --cached Word Guess/bin
```

I got the same error as before

```
fatal: pathspec 'Word' did not match any files
```

Then I tried with the alternative name representation

```
git rm --cached Word\ Guess/bin
```

That gave me the following error:

```
error: the following file has staged content different from both the file and the HEAD: 
Word Guess/bin
(use -f to force removal)
```

see screen shot below:

[image: git add error 3]

I am at a total loss now for how to proceed and am frustrated that I seemingly cannot even undo the mistaken commands.

Comment: The first half of your question is irrelevant btw. You figured out that you need to escape white space.

Comment: What is in Word Guess’s bin folder?

Comment: @JBallin inside the bin folder is the following: ".git" folder, "README.md" file, "WordGuess.class" file, and a strange file titled ".[A.[C.[B" I have no idea what that last file is and the dots aren't normal periods they are higher up almost like a '*' character

Comment: The `∙[A∙[C∙[B` file is probably the result of turning arrow keys or similar into a file name.

Answer (score 2):

Your `Word Guess` directory (folder, if you prefer) contains a Git repository.  A Git repository cannot contain another Git repository, so the "outer" Git refuses to add the entire inner repository.  It does add *something*, but the thing it adds is not the Git repository: it adds, instead, a *submodule*, which is a *reference to* another Git repository.

This makes the outer Git act as a so-called *superproject*.  When one clones a superproject, the superproject contains a reference to some other Git project, and `git submodule init` or `git submodule update --init` knows to read the instructions for "where do I clone this other Git project from" and clone it.  A later `git checkout --recursive`, or `git submodule update --checkout`, uses the stored information about which *commit* is to be checked-out in the submodule.

To add a submodule correctly, you need to use `git submodule add`, not `git add`.  You use `git add` to *update* the submodule linkage, but only *after* `git submodule add` adds the submodule correctly.  If you use `git add` to add the submodule initially, you get what I sometimes call a "half-assed" submodule: one that lacks the instructions about where, in some other clone of the superproject, Git is supposed to clone the submodule *from*.  Without that information, a new clone of the superproject knows that it needs commit `a123456` (or whatever) of some other Git repository, but has no clue where it should clone that other Git repository *from*.  (That's not very useful unless you plan to manually clone the submodule yourself, which is why I call it "half-assed".)

In the bad old days of Git 1.5, 1.6, and early 1.7, people used to refer to submodules as sob-modules, because the tooling was so bad it would make one cry.  It's still ... not that good, and I think some people still use this phrase.  If you do want a submodule, be *really sure* you want a submodule.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification.  I definitely did not intend to create a submodule, does that mean that I was in the wrong root directory when attempting the add command.  The directory path that contains my project is: C:\Users\Gabe\OneDrive\Documents\School\GitHub projects\Word Guess I thought the directory path that contains my local repository is: C:\Users\Gabe\OneDrive\Documents\School\GitHub projects  I was executing commands in git bash one level up from the Word Guess folder, is that not right?

Comment: also how might I undo this, when I followed the instructions on git bash and executed the "git rm" command it only seemed to further compound the issue as seen in my last screen shot

Comment: It's not necessarily an *error*. It's just the way Git is designed, that gives you this limitation: you must either not *try* to put a Git repository into a Git repository—by not using a Git repository as a subdirectory of another Git repository—or else accept the submodule-ness. To remove the half-assed submodule use `git rm` but, as before, *quote the space* because your particular command line interpreter is a Linux/Unix-ish one that thinks spaces are not part of file names.

Comment: To avoid trying to put a Git repository into another Git repository, when you're working within the outer repository, don't clone or create any new Git repositories inside its working tree. If you have some other Git repository, with some particular commit, that you want to take its *files* from, clone that other Git repository somewhere else, then *copy the working tree files* into the working tree of the first Git repository. (This gets pretty confusing without names for everyone. It's like being at Bruce University, where everyone is named Bruce. Also the buses are called Bruces.)